# Fork multiple children in Perl and use pipes for bi-directional communication

Tags: perl, fork, pipe

I am trying to create a small Perl program which has multi processing capabilities. Since there are some small changes here and there in my requirements, I am not able to find any similar sample scripts anywhere.

I need to read a big logfile from STDIN and give first N number (a big number again) of lines to the first child process and then next N number of lines to the second child process etc. I have also a constant defined which is the maximum number of child processes allowed to run concurrently. Once maximum number of children reached, parent will wait for a child to finish its job and give another N number of lines to it.

The parent process also collects a multi-line (5-10 lines) output returned by each child process when they finish and stores it in an array. Parent then continues to process this array contents and display the results finally.

Is there a better sample script which I can modify and use or could someone help me by sharing one here? I prefer using only pipes for process intercommunication and keep things simpler as much as possible.

Edit:
Can someone show an example how this can be accomplished only using pipes from IO::Handle module ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper), which makes it easy to throttle the number of simultaneous processes and handle the interprocess communication. For example,

```
use Forks::Super MAX_PROC => 10,     # allow 10 simultaneous processes
                 ON_BUSY => 'queue'; # don't block when >=10 jobs are active

@loglines = <>;

# set up all the background jobs
while (@loglines > 0) {
    $pid = fork {
        args => [ splice @loglines, 0, $N ],  # to pass to sub, below
        child_fh => "out",    # make child STDOUT readable by parent
        sub => sub {
            my @loglines = @_;
            my @result = ... do something with loglines ...
            print @results;   # use $pid->read_stdout() to read in child
        }
    };
}

# get the results
while ($pid = waitpid -1, 0) {
    last if $pid == -1;
    my @results_from_job = $pid->read_stdout();
    push @results, @results_from_job;
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I exactly wanted. But I run this script in a restricted environment where only a limited number of Perl modules are available. Can we use IO::Handle alone and achieve the same?

Answer (score -1):

I have found threads to be much simpler for this sort of process.  You need the threads and Threads::Queue modules.  The process is to set up a queue to feed the worker threads and one for them to return their results.  The worker thread is just a function to read a record, process it and send a result back.  I just put this code together and have not tested it so it may be buggy but I think shows the general idea:

```
use threads ();
use Thread::Queue;
#
#
#            Set limit on number of workers
#
my $MAX_THREADS = 5;
my $EOD = "\n\n";
#
#
#            Need a queue to feed the workers
#            and one for them to return results
#
my $Qresult  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $rec;
my $n;
#
#
#            load STDIN into the input queue
#
my $Qin = Thread::Queue->new(<>);
#
#
#            start worker threads
#
for($n = 0; $n < $MAX_THREADS; ++$n)
{
    async{ProcessRecord($n);};
    $Qin->enqueue($EOD);            #    need terminator for each
}
#
#
#
#            Wait for the results to come in
#
$n = 0;
while($n < $MAX_THREADS)
{
            $rec = $q->dequeue();
            if($rec eq $EOD)
            {
                ++$n;
                next;
            }

            :
            :
            :
    #-- process result --#
            :
            :
            :


    threads->yield();    #    let other threads get a chance
    sleep 1;
}
exit;    
######################################    
#
#
#            Worker threads draw from the queue
#            when a "terminator" is read, quit;
#
sub ProcessRecord 
{
    my $rec;
    my $result;

    while(1)
    {
        $rec = $Qin->dequeue();
        last if $rec eq $EOD;
            :
            :
            :
        #-- process record --#
            :
            :
            :
        $Qresult->enqueue($result);

        threads->yield();    #    let other threads get a chance
    }

    threads->exit();    
}
```